# How can I access the usernames from this query

Tags: swift, parse-platform, segue

1.I am trying to base my segue off if the current user is an admin role or employee role. 
2.The problem seems to be after the Role query...i can println the list of that roles names to the console in an array...but I'm having trouble figuring out how to see if the current user is in that list AND if they are in that list then segue accordingly.. Thanks in advance!

```
   func checkEmployeeOrAdmin() {
 var roleQuery = PFRole.query()
roleQuery!.whereKey("name", equalTo: "admin")
roleQuery!.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock() { (roleObject: PFObject?, error) -> Void in


var adminRole = roleObject as! PFRole


    adminRole.users.query()?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (users, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    if let adminUsers = users as? [PFUser] {

    if adminUsers.usernames == PFUser.currentUser()?.username     {


     **//error is here....[PFUser] does not have a member named username...


      println("\(adminUsers)")


       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toAdmin", sender: self)

    }else {

      println("nothingFound")
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toEmployee", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't compare by username, can you guarantee they will always be globally unique? You should either compare the whole user object or the `objectId`.

Your current code is trying to ask an Array for its username, which it doesn't have. Instead you should iterate the objects in the array and ask each one separately then compare.

You could create a reusable function for that, or you could use the `NSArray` method `containsObject:` which would do it for you.

With the swift Array you can also use `filter` to run a logical test against each item in the array and return the matches (then check the count of the matches).